# Running a method just once at the beginning before any tests are run in PyUnit

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, python-unittest

Im using PyUnit to write unit tests for my code. The setup method is called everytime before any test is run.
Is there a way i can define a method that will be run just once at the beginning before any tests are run ?

Please Help
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [setUpClass or setUpModule](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html?highlight=setupclass#setupclass-and-teardownclass) in Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the constructor of your test class?

Comment: I tried defining  `__init__` in my test class, but it gives the error `__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` . Any reason why this happens in a class inheriting from unittest.TestCase ?

Comment: `unittest.TestCase` takes a `methodName` as parameter, so it can be initialized with 2 arguments, `self` and `methodName`. Your test class probably only takes one argument, `self`.